# Как открыть локальную страницу в Mozila Firefox

Tags: firefox

В папке с профилем лежит html страничка как ее открить, тоесть в адресной строке нужно написать команду на подобее path но как она в фаерфокс пишется то?

**ВОПРОС РЕШЕН**
Сам я вопрос решил, но тут я не корректно написал его. Посколько удалить я его не могу пишу вот такое сообщение.

Comment: `file:///` + путь к html ?

Comment: "Посколько удалить я его не могу" - уточните пожалуйста, разве у вас нет кнопки удалить под вопросом?

Comment: @Kromster кнопка есть, но при попытке удалить вот такое сообщение "Приносим свои извинения, но на этот вопрос уже получены ответы, и удалять его нельзя; "

Answer (score 2):

Несколько способов открыть локальный файл в Firefox:

- правой кнопкой по файлу "Открыть с помощью Firefox";
- в самом Firefox "Файл -> Открыть файл";
- прописать в адресной строке путь к файлу: `file:///home/path/to/file`;
- из консоли:

  - открыть в новом окне: `firefox --new-window file.txt`
  - открыть в новой вкладке: `firefox --new-tab file.txt`

Comment: Это протейбл версия, и в папке с самой програмой лежит страничка, поскольку браузер будет переносится от компа к компу нужно какой то патч, как то так.

Comment: Перечитайте свой вопрос и сравните с моим ответом. В вопросе ни о какой программе речи не идёт, но даже если так, поправьте сам вопрос. И что такое "протейбл"

Comment: @edem: Думаю, это «portable».