# Руководство по изучению JavaScript

Tags: javascript

*Пробная версия по написанию книг, в данном случае по языку JavaScript. Подробнее здесь: [Как мы хотим начать писать Книги сообщества?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6523)*

### Содержание

#### Программы на JavaScript

- Где разрабатывать?
- Как их запускать?
- Как тестировать?
- Как отлаживать?
- Библиотеки JS:

  - как писать?
  - в чём их отличие?
  - распространённые библиотеки JS.
- Какие задачи выполняют программы на JS?

#### Структура языка

- Переменные
- Циклы
- Функции
- Версии стандартов языка и в чём их отличие?

#### Связка с HTML и CSS

- Манипуляция DOM
- Изменение свойств CSS HTML элементов.

#### Веб-сервер

- Как происходит обмен данными с веб-сервером?

#### Безопасность

- Как закодировать JS код для затруднения отладки другими?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70484/discussion-on-question-by-edem----javascript).

Answer (score 3):

Программы на JavaScript могут запускаться:

- в браузере;
- на сервере (NodeJS, PhantomJS и т.п).

В браузере код может быть выполнен из:

- Консоли разработчика.
- Непосредственно из кода страницы:

  - из меток `<script>...</script>`;
  - из подключаемых скриптов `<script src="file.js"></script>`;
  - из встроенных обработчиков событий: `<div onclick="alert(8)"></div>`;
- Из адресной строки: `data:text/html,<script>alert(8)</script>`

Страницы, содержащие выполняемый JS код, могут его выполнить в двух случаях:

- на локальном компьютере без веб-сервера в качестве посредника, т.е. когда просто запускаем html страницу в браузере как обычный файл ([пример для Firefox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/628230/199733));
- непосредственно с использованием веб-сервера: Apache, nginx и т.п.

Задачи программ на JS:

- работа с видимой частью страницы: HTML DOM, CSS.
- взаимодействие с браузером: Cookies, LocalStorage, History и т.п.
- взаимодействие с веб-сервером:

  - технологии Ajax;
  - технологии WebSocket.
- логика приложения: функции и методы, реализующие непосредственного функционал приложения.